# pset9 finance expected status code 200, but got 403

Tags: cs50

I just completed pset 9 and everything works just fine (apparently!) but, whenever I run check50, I get back:

```
:) app.py exists
:) application starts up
:) register page has all required elements
:) registering user succeeds and portfolio page is displayed
:) registration with an empty field fails
:) registration with password mismatch fails
:) registration rejects duplicate username
:) login page has all required elements
:( logging in as a registered user succeeds
expected status code 200, but got 403
:| quote page has all required elements
can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| quote handles invalid ticker symbol
can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| quote handles blank ticker symbol
can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| quote handles valid ticker symbol
can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| buy page has all required elements
can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| buy handles invalid ticker symbol
can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| buy handles fractional, negative, and non-numeric shares
can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| buy handles valid purchase
can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| sell page has all required elements
can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| sell handles invalid number of shares
can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| sell handles valid sale
can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| history page shows transactions
can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

I have no idea what's the case here (I was under the impression that the login funtion was taken care of by the staff).

***Would be immensely grateful for advice! Have already submitted my final project and this is the only one holding me up from completing the course. Any guidance would be massively appreciated. Thank you!***

```
import os

from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from datetime import datetime

from helpers import apology, login_required, lookup, usd

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Custom filter
app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response


@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
    cash_left = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
    cashr = cash_left[0]["cash"]

    total_stocks = 0

    if not db.execute("SELECT symbol FROM purch WHERE user_id = ?", session["user_id"]):
            return apology("no stocks in portfolio", 403)

    all_stock_names = db.execute("SELECT symbol FROM purch WHERE user_id = ?", session["user_id"])

    for i in all_stock_names:
        db.execute("UPDATE purch SET price = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?", lookup(i["symbol"])['price'], session["user_id"], i["symbol"])


    ptfl = db.execute("SELECT * FROM purch WHERE user_id = ?", session["user_id"])

    for i in ptfl:
        total_stocks = total_stocks + float(i["price"]) * float(i["quantity"])

    total_amt = total_stocks + cashr

    return render_template("index.html", portfolio = ptfl, cash_remainder = cashr, tval = total_stocks, tamt = total_amt)


@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "POST":

        if not request.form.get("symbol"):
            return apology("must provide symbol", 403)

        elif not request.form.get("shares"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        if lookup(request.form.get("symbol")) == None:
            return apology("No Match Found", 403)

        cash_list = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
        cash = float(cash_list[0]["cash"])
        price = float(lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))['price'])
        quantity = float(request.form.get("shares"))

        expenditure = quantity * price

        if expenditure > cash:
            return apology("Insufficient Funds", 403)

        user_name = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
        user = user_name[0]["username"]

        money_left = cash - expenditure

        undertaking = "Bought"

        update = False

        p = db.execute("SELECT * FROM purch")

        for i in p:
            if i["symbol"] == request.form.get("symbol") and i["user_id"] == session["user_id"]:
                of = db.execute("SELECT quantity FROM purch WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?", session["user_id"], request.form.get("symbol"))
                nf = of[0]["quantity"] + quantity
                db.execute("UPDATE purch SET price = ?, quantity = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?", price, nf, session["user_id"], request.form.get("symbol"))
                update = True
                break

        if update == False:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO purch (user_id, username, symbol, price, quantity) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", session["user_id"], user, request.form.get("symbol"), price, quantity)

        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", money_left, session["user_id"])
        db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, action, price, quantity, date, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", session["user_id"], request.form.get("symbol"), undertaking, price, quantity, datetime.now().date(), datetime.now().time())

        return redirect("/")

    else:
        return render_template("buyit.html")


@app.route("/history")
@login_required
def history():
    """Show history of transactions"""
    ptfl = db.execute("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id = ?", session["user_id"])
    return render_template("tracker.html", hist = ptfl)


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
            return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    """Log user out"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # Redirect user to login form
    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def quote():
    """Get stock quote."""
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not request.form.get("symbol"):
            return apology("must provide stock symbol", 403)

        if lookup(request.form.get("symbol")) == None:
            return apology("No Match Found", 403)

        stk = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))

        return render_template("quoted.html", stock=stk)

    else:
        return render_template("quotations.html")


@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 400)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 400)

        elif not request.form.get("confirmation"):
            return apology("must provide confirmation", 400)

        elif not request.form.get("confirmation") == request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("password does not match confirmation", 400)

        username = request.form.get("username")
        users = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users")

        for i in users:
            if username == i['username']:
                return apology("User already exists", 400)

        hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))

        db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (?, ?)", username, hash)

        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", username)

        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        return redirect("/login", 200)

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("registration.html")


@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():
    """Sell shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "POST":

        if not request.form.get("symbol"):
            return apology("must provide symbol", 403)

        elif not request.form.get("shares"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        elif not db.execute("SELECT quantity FROM purch WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?", session["user_id"], request.form.get("symbol")):
            return apology("operation not possible", 403)

        q = db.execute("SELECT quantity FROM purch WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?", session["user_id"], request.form.get("symbol"))

        quant = q[0]["quantity"]

        if quant < float(request.form.get("shares")):
            return apology("not enough shares", 403)

        cash_list = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
        cash = float(cash_list[0]["cash"])
        price = float(lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))['price'])
        quantity = float(request.form.get("shares"))

        earnings = quantity * price

        user_name = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
        user = user_name[0]["username"]

        money_left = cash + earnings

        remainder = (quant - quantity)

        undertaking = "Sold"

        db.execute("UPDATE purch SET price = ?, quantity = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?", price, remainder, session["user_id"], request.form.get("symbol"))
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", money_left, session["user_id"])
        db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, action, price, quantity, date, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", session["user_id"], request.form.get("symbol"), undertaking, price, quantity, datetime.now().date(), datetime.now().time())

        return redirect("/", 200)

    else:
        return render_template("selloff.html")

@app.route("/change", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def change():
    """Change user password"""

    if request.method == "POST":

        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        elif not request.form.get("current"):
            return apology("must provide previous", 403)

        elif not request.form.get("new"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        elif not request.form.get("confirmation"):
            return apology("must provide confirmation", 403)

        x = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])

        now = x[0]["hash"]

        if check_password_hash(now, request.form.get("new")):
            return apology("This password is in use", 403)

        elif not request.form.get("new") == request.form.get("confirmation"):
            return apology("New password and confirmation don't match", 403)

        if x[0]["username"] == request.form.get("username") and check_password_hash(now, request.form.get("current")):
            db.execute("UPDATE users SET hash = ? WHERE id = ?", generate_password_hash(request.form.get("new")), session["user_id"])
        else:
            return apology("Username or Password doesn't match records", 403)

        return redirect("/")

    else:
        return render_template("pwd.html")
-----------------------------------------------
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Log In
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
-----------------------------------------------
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Registration
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="confirmation" name="confirmation" placeholder="confirmation" type="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register Me!</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
-----------------------------------------------
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Log In
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried re-editing the login, register and change password functions, forcuefully passing in 200 to the return functions, changing the 403 return values to 200 individually to identify the source of the issue. However, nothing worked.

I have tried the program by myself and it works just fine then. I therefore expected it to pass check50 without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the 403

```
if not db.execute("SELECT symbol FROM purch WHERE user_id = ?", session["user_id"]):
            return apology("no stocks in portfolio", 403)
```

`check50` registers a new user who has no holdings. Program should display the index page even if user has no holdings.